# How do I get the name input to read whitespaces

Tags: java, user-input, whitespace

So im having trouble getting the first read input to read all inputs on the line. But for some reason it doesnt take into consideration of whitespaces. in fact, it considers the whitespace from the print information as part of the whitespace. only name has this problem. ID does not have this problem. I would just like to know how to fix this one problem since it is giving me the most trouble.

```
public class Project2 {
    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonList PersonList = new PersonList();
        
        System.out.print("Welcome to my personal Management Program\n\n");
        System.out.print("\nChoose one of the following options: \n\n");
        
        //print out options for user 
        for (;;) {
            int input = 0;
            System.out.print("1- Enter the information of a faculty\n");
            System.out.print("2- Enter the information of a student\n");
            System.out.print("3- Print tuition person for a student\n");
            System.out.print("4- Print faculty information\n");
            System.out.print("5- Enter the information of a staff member\n");
            System.out.print("6- Print the information of a staff member\n");
            System.out.print("7-Exit the program\n\n");
            System.out.print("\tEnter a selection: ");
                input = sc.nextInt();
                
                if (input == 1) {
                    faculty f = new faculty();
                    System.out.print("Enter the faculty info:\n");
                    System.out.print("\tName of Faculty: ");
                    f.name = sc.nextLine();
                    
                    System.out.print("\tID: ");
                    f.ID = sc.nextLine();
                    
                    String rank, department;
                    for(;;) {
                        System.out.print("\n\tRank: ");
                        rank = sc.nextLine();
                        if (rank.equalsIgnoreCase("professor") || rank.equalsIgnoreCase("adjunct")) {
                            f.rank = rank;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.print("\"" + rank +"\" is invalid");
                        }
                    }
                    for(;;) {
                        System.out.print("\tDepartment: ");
                        department = sc.nextLine();
                        if (department.equalsIgnoreCase("mathematics") || department.equalsIgnoreCase("engineering") || department.equalsIgnoreCase("sciences")) {
                            f.Department = department;
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.print("\"" + department +"\" is invalid");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Faculty added!");
                    PersonList.addPerson(f);
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Answer (score 0):

When you read the selection `input = sc.nextInt()` it returns the next integer it finds, stopping right after that. It returns the choice typed but it *does not read* the newline. If you typed  `1`  (space one space) it would skip over the leading space then read the 1 and *stop*; it would not read the following space or the newline.

So when you get to the faculty name `f.name = sc.nextLine()` it reads whatever was remaining from the `input =`  line, which is probably just a newline, and returns *that* for the name.
Now when you get to `f.ID = sc.nextLine()` the input buffer is clear so it reads ID as you expect it to.

A simple solution is to just finish reading the line by adding a nextLine() after reading the selection:

```java
System.out.print("\tEnter a selection: ");
input = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine(); // Read the remainder of the line and throw it away
```

Read the javadoc for [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and for [`nextInt()` and `nextInt(radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--)